# Trying to resize an image on an HTML page through external CSS

Tags: css, html

So currently I am very new to CSS, and am trying to work on my portfolio page. I have my page sourcing my external CSS style sheet, and most other elements are working, but i cant seem to resize a few images

my HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/tammer-galal/108/259/5a7" target="_blank" title="LinkedIn">
             <img class="clicklinks" src="images/linkedin.png">
```

my CSS:

```
img.clicklinks {
    height: 45px;
    width: auto;
}
```

the problem is this doesn't effect my images with the class of clicklinks at all. Trying to figure out where i'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

**SOLVED. Thank you.**

Comment: One problem is: `height: 45px` should be `height: 45px;` with a trailing semicolon.

Comment: fixed, thank you. solved!

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a `;` after 45px and it should work.